# php script with multiple buttons

Tags: php, forms, button

The idea is the page in which you select a category from drop-down menu, then after you click remove button, new form shows(contains yes/no buttons) that asks you if you really want to remove selected category. Problem is the second yes/no script. It works on separate page, but on page with first form it doesn't echo anything nor does it remove a pet. Please help, thanks!

```
<?php
/*remove a category*/
include("connection.php");
?>
<html><head></head>
<body>
<?php
$PetListquery= "SELECT distinct petType From petType ORDER by petType";
$PetListResult= mysqli_query($cxn,$PetListquery) or die ("Couldn't execute query.");
?>
<div style="border:2px solid;">
<form method="POST" action="removeCategory.php">
<div align='left'>
Choose category you want to remove:
<select name='petType'>
    <option value='-1'>Type:</option>
    <?php 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($PetListResult))
    {
        extract($row);
        ?>
        <option value='<?php echo $petType;?>' ><?php echo $petType;?> </option>
<?php   }?>
</select>
</div>

<div>
<p><input type='submit' name='Remove' value='Remove Category' />
</div>
</div>
</form>

<?php

foreach($_POST as $field => $value)
{   //second form starts after if
if($field == 'petType')
{
    ?>
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
    <div>
    <input name="Yes" type="submit" value="Yes">
    <input name="No" type="submit" value="No">
    </div>
    </form>
    <?php
    echo "Are you sure you want to delete selected category?";
    //clicking any of these buttons doesn't display anything
    if(isset($_POST['Yes']))
    {
    echo "yes";
    $DeleteQuery= "DELETE From petType WHERE petType='$petType'";
    $DeleteResult= mysqli_query($cxn,$DeleteQuery) or die ("Error1!");
    }

    if(isset($_POST['No']))
    {
    echo "No!";
    }

}
}

?>
</body></html>
```

Comment: `if($field == 'petType') to if($value== 'petType')`

Comment: Are you able to get the drop-down menu, as desired ??

Comment: yes, drop-down menu is fine, petType is field name(i use it to filter out the foreach going twice), value is variable based on drop-down menu, so putting it to petType wont make much sense i think...